# How to bind facebox object dynamically with dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, facebox

```
function test()
{
    //load some data through ajax call 
    html = '<a rel="facebox_edit" href="www.google.com">abc</a>';
    $('#id_fv').html(html);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('a[rel*=facebox_edit]').facebox({
                    loadingImage : full_path+'images/loading.gif',
                    closeImage   : full_path+'images/closelabel.png'
                });
            });
```

On body load I call the function test(),
now when I click the link it directly go to www.google.com page rather than loading it in facebox. how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Write like this..

```
function test()
{
    //load some data through ajax call 
    html = '<a rel="facebox_edit" href="www.google.com">abc</a>';
    $('#id_fv').html(html);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                test();
                $('a[rel*=facebox_edit]').facebox({
                    loadingImage : full_path+'images/loading.gif',
                    closeImage   : full_path+'images/closelabel.png'
                });
            });
```